# Can a mathematical function be assigned to ECG diagram?

Tags: biophysics, electrocardiography

This is a 12 lead electeocardiogram of a 26 year old male: [image]

This is the graph of function $5sin(7x)sin(.5x)cos(3.25x)$
[image] This graph look *quite* similar to the ECG diagram.After sketching this graph, I thought whether ECG diagram could be assigned *roughly* to a mathematical function.

**Question:** Has anyone ever tried to even roughly assign the diagram to a mathematical function? Is it even possible?

Comment: *"Has anyone ever tried to even roughly assign the diagram to a mathematical function?"* Yes, it was done before, using [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) (kind of what you have in your graph). The result is far from beautiful, see here: https://www.intmath.com/fourier-series/ecg-fourier-quartic-plusT.pdf. And here a detailed explanation: https://www.intmath.com/blog/mathematics/math-of-ecgs-fourier-series-4281

Comment: The links are broken or I can't open them from my android

Comment: Fourier series was my first guess, too. Is there any particular reason you would like to do that? I'm asking because if fitting is your concern, wavelet decomposition may be easier to work with. By the way, the links work for me.

Comment: @Mockingbird the links are up.

Comment: Yes, this would require [Fourier series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html), in which case you would then desire to establish the number of terms needed to best fit your data, and, at the same time, find the value for each term's coefficient. If you have the raw data, you can upload to it Wolfram alpha and it will generate a function that fits. For [example](http://www.businessinsider.com/awesome-things-you-can-do-with-wolfram-alpha-2013-7?op=1/#-you-can-use-the-site-for-shopping-and-market-research-28), WA can generate a function for Obama's signature; #26 on the list.

Comment: I recommend checking out [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/364371/316270) Mathematics.SE post, which nicely outlines Fourier series.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about biology.

Answer (score 3):

Yes a function could be assigned to an ECG diagram. I don't know if that would be helpful in any kind of research. Anyway I believe that from a mathematical point of view that if you manage to include all the equations shown in the picture into a single one you should get what you are looking for.
[image: Decomposition of the ECG signal]

I have not made the diagram it was taken from this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/286584223_Design_of_a_synthetic_ECG_signal_based_on_the_Fourier_series by Radana Kahankova.

Comment: I was a high school back then when I asked this question. Obviously I had no emphasis on the graphical analysis being useful. haha

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

$f(x)=-20(e^{\left(\operatorname{mod}\left(x-10,\ 20\right)-10\right)}*(e^{5\left(\operatorname{mod}\left(x-10,\ 20\right)-10\right)}-57*e^{4\left(\operatorname{mod}\left(x-10,\ 20\right)-10\right)}+302*e^{3\left(\operatorname{mod}\left(x-10,\ 20\right)-10\right)}-302*e^{2\left(\operatorname{mod}\left(x-10,\ 20\right)-10\right)}+57*e^{\left(\operatorname{mod}\left(x-10,\ 20\right)-10\right)}-1))/(e^{\left(\operatorname{mod}\left(x-10,\ 20\right)-10\right)}+1)^7$

Comment: Er, how does anyone know whether this is right or not?

Comment: Just copy the tex and paste it here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: To be clear, there is really no biological reason to do this. ECGs are not collections of these sorts of functions. Fitting something like this is just a curiosity and gives you no understanding that you can't find in the original signal.

Comment: @Amad I see what you did here. You ploted a graph that slightly resenbles an ECG (Only QRST). Appreciate your intend to answer but I am afraid this is not what the author of the question's looking for.

Comment: @BryanKrause Haha I was a teenager back then when I asked this question and had no interest in the biological importance of the graphical analysis

Comment: @Mockingbird Yeah, that's kind of what I figured, I'm just going to close it. It's effectively a variant of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real which is also closed over at Math.SE.